# Check if Direct Carrier Billing is enable programmatically

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I would like to check programmatically if a user has the carrier billing enabled.

I'm reading the docs here. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: I don't know of any method to be able to get info on payment methods, that is handled by the playstore, not the developer.